# Difference between Asyncdata vs Fetch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

What is the exact difference between fetch and async data. The official documentation says the following:

> **asyncData**
>
> You may want to fetch data and render it on the server-side. Nuxt.js
> adds an asyncData method that lets you handle async operations before
> setting the component data.
>
> **asyncData** is called every time before loading the component (only for
> page components). It can be called from the server-side or before
> navigating to the corresponding route. This method receives the
> context object as the first argument, you can use it to fetch some
> data and return the component data.

---

> **Fetch**
>
> The fetch method is used to fill the store before rendering the page, it's
> like the asyncData method except it doesn't set the component data.
> The fetch method, if set, is called every time before loading the
> component (only for page components). It can be called from the
> server-side or before navigating to the corresponding route.
>
> The fetch method receives the context object as the first argument, we
> can use it to fetch some data and fill the store. To make the fetch
> method asynchronous, return a Promise, nuxt.js will wait for the
> promise to be resolved before rendering the component.

---

Fetch is been used to fill the store with data? But in asyncData is this also possible to commit trough a store? I don't understand why there are two methods for.

Both methods are running server-side on the initial load, after that when you navigate through the applicatie it runs client side.

Can someone explain me the advantage of use these methods above the other?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Let me re-iterate few points as a pretext to what i'm going to say

- `asyncData` can set component level objects and access vuex store
- `fetch` cannot set component level objects but has access to vuex store
- Both `asyncData` & `fetch` will be triggered in server side during initial load
- After initial load, `asyncData` and `fetch` will be triggered when the corresponding page routes are invoked

**1) if your design is**

- Use vuex store as a central repository
- Access data from the vuex store for the entire application

then `use fetch`

**2) if your design is**

- Use vuex store as a central repository
- Have options to set component level objects
- Data fetched in a particular route is used only by a single component
- Need flexibility to have permission to either vuex store or set component level object

then `use asyncData`

> Can someone explain me the advantage of use these methods above the
>   other?

i don't see any drawbacks in using `asyncData` or `fetch`

Choosing `asyncData` or `fetch` totally depends on your architecture

## Update for NuxtJS >= 2.12

Several points mentioned in the answer no longer apply when using newer NuxtJS versions (>= [2.12](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v2.12.0)). Official RFC announcement [here](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/27).

A good explanation of the new behaviour and differences between `asyncData` and the new `fetch` can be found in this [post](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12) in the NuxtJS official blog.

As for choosing between both, I believe the original answer still applies:

> i don't see any drawbacks in using `asyncData` or `fetch`
>
> Choosing `asyncData` or `fetch` totally depends on your architecture

Comment: upvoted! can I call fetch manually, i have a universal mode nuxt app where on one page I must paginate a table fetching data from the server without changing the page, if I click next page button should I call fetch manually or how

Comment: @PirateApp my practical experience is,  you cannot execute 'fetch' manually, behavior of 'fetch' is controlled by nuxtjs. if you need to trigger any events (for dataFetch) after pageLoad, better to write a customMethod for dataFetch and bind the 'nextPage button' to it

Comment: What about not using them at all, and using created or mounted hooks instead?

Comment: @PrimozRome `created & mounted` hooks always runs on the client side. on first request to the nuxtapp for a particular route `asyncData & fetch` will run on the server side. So with `asyncData & fetch`, you have the opportunity to load the data into client without any ajax request after page load in client side as you would do for `created & mounted` hooks

Comment: @divine yes that is correct, thanks for explanation. I forgot to mention in my comment if using Nuxt.js app in SPA mode only. Then it should be the same using `fetch()` or `created()`
 hook, correct?

Comment: @PrimozRome yes correct, in spa whatever goes into `asyncData` or `fetch` will be invoked first then `created` hook gets invoked then `mounted` hook gets invoked. So `asyncData` or `fetch` gets invoked before the component gets `created`.

Comment: I want to fill the VUEX store with data in the fetch method. Is this data then available in the asyncData method? I cannot understand which one runs first...

Comment: @divine To clarify: are the created and mounted hooks called server side in nuxt?  If so, the only reason to use asyncData would be timing.

Comment: To emphasize: `asyncData` is only in 'pages' not in 'components.' Must use `fetch` in that one. Strangely, when making this mistake of using `asyncData` in a 'components' file, there is no warning or linting error. ‍♂️

Comment: But doesn't fetch has access to component context with `this`? Then it can set data like this.someData = data;  -> `With the help of this context, fetch is able to mutate component’s data directly.`

Comment: > "yes correct, in spa whatever goes into asyncData or fetch will be invoked first then created hook gets invoked" - if you check update in nuxt 2.12 fetch() is called after create()

Comment: a drawback of using fetch() is that you can't insert requested data at page headers

Answer (score 24):

TL;DR - use `asyncData` for stuff which must be loaded before rendering a page, use `fetch` for everything else.

Key differences:

#### Availability

- `asyncData` is only available on page components
- `fetch` can be used on any component (including page components)

#### Loading

- `asyncData` blocks the page transition until it resolves. This means the data properties returned are guaranteed to be available on the component. But it also means users may have to wait longer before seeing content.
- `fetch` exposes a `$fetchState.pending` property and it's up to you how to handle that

#### Error handling

- if an error is thrown in `asyncData` the page is not rendered
- `fetch` exposes a `$fetchState.error` property and it's up to you how to handle that

Comment: That said, in a SSG site we "should" use ```asyncData``` for retrieving data for a page that will not change during navigation and, for example, set the dynamic meta tags in the head method (if using ```fetch()```, ```head()``` could not receive the data in time). We should use ```fetch()``` when we want more control on the data received, for example if there is a button to trigger the ```fetch()``` again while showing a placeholder with ```$fetchState.pending```. Am I thinking it right?

Comment: @StefanoFranceschetto makes sense

Comment: The section on "loading" really clarifies things for me.

Answer (score 8):

One point I'd like to make that I don't see mentioned above (at least, not clearly).
asyncData automatically MERGES the data into your page's data() object. Fetch does not. With fetch, it's up to you to do with the data as you please.

Answer (score 7):

### The 1st

Because of the different nature of `asyncData` and `fetch` there is one important advantage in case of `asyncData` - Nuxt waits for the asyncData hook to be finished before navigating to the next page.

[Taking from here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data):

> Unlike fetch, the promise returned by the asyncData hook is resolved during route transition. This means that no "loading placeholder" is visible during client-side transitions (although the loading bar can be used to indicate a loading state to the user). Nuxt will instead wait for the asyncData hook to be finished before navigating to the next page or display the error page).

What does it mean on practise?

Lets imagine you have the next structure of layout:

- Header
- Content
- Footer

In case of using `fetch` when you open a new page, you may see for few seconds just Header and Footer (because data for Content is downloading). In case of using `asyncData` you avoid this problem and see a new page with Header + Content + Footer (however the disadvantage of this method is that you need to wait the same few seconds to download Content data).

### The 2nd

I see in different places in web that when you want to store something in vuex, you need to use `fetch` - this is incorrect.

In the code below (taken from my project) you can find implementation of `asyncData` and `fetch` that both store data into vuex.

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'PagesBlog',

  async asyncData ({ store }) {
    if (!store.state.global.blogAuthors.length) {
      store.commit('global/blogAuthorsSet', await blogAuthorsDownload())
    }

    await store.dispatch('global/blogsDownloadAndSet')
  },

  async fetch () {
    if (!this.blogAuthors.length) {
      this.blogAuthorsSet(await blogAuthorsDownload())
    }

    await this.blogsDownloadAndSet()
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState('global', [
      'blogAuthors'
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions('global', [
      'blogsDownloadAndSet'
    ]),

    ...mapMutations('global', [
      'blogAuthorsSet'
    ])
  }
</script>
```

### Summary

1. If you have some important data (either visible to user or not visible to user, but needed for some hidden calculation) - use `asyncData`.
2. If you want to see page with all information (for example when you have Header + Content + Footer) - use `asyncData`.
3. If you have some data that can be loaded a bit later - use `fetch`.

---

[Fetch Hook and Nuxt Lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/#fetch-hook-and-nuxt-lifecycle)

Answer (score 5):

I. fetch and asyncData are processed on the server-side.

II. can see the difference in the way to use them:

**a) fetch: change store data**

```
<script>
export default {
  async fetch ({ store, params }) {
    await store.dispatch('GET_STARS');
  }
}
</script>
```

**b) asyncData: change context (component data)**

```
<script>
export default {
  asyncData (context) {
    return { project: 'nuxt' }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is incorrect example. While asyncData indeed can change local/component data, you can use it to save data in store as well. Simply replace "fetch" by "asyncData" in your example, that's it.