# How to properly use the new fetch() hook in Nuxt 2.12 for SSR?

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I updated Nuxt to the latest version because they introduced the new `fetch()` hook.
In my project, I'm retrieving data from Prismic. Before, I was using `asyncData()`, but when navigating, it took some time before rendering the pages where `asyncData()` was invoked (this is how it works).

The ideal solution is to navigate on that particular page, and show a loading animation while retrieving the data. 
The new `fetch()` hook seems appropriate because it exposes the `$fetchState.pending` in order to check the status of the operation.

Now, the code (I'm retrieving subcategories from the category in a shop):

```js
        data(){
            return{
                docs: []
            }
        },

        async fetch() {
            try{
                const res = await this.$prismic.api.query(this.$prismic.predicates.at('my.category.uid', this.$route.params.sub))
                const el = res.results[0]
                const query = await this.$prismic.api.query([this.$prismic.predicates.at('document.type','sub-category'), this.$prismic.predicates.at('my.sub-category.category', el.id)], { orderings: '[my.sub-category.position, my.sub-category.title]' })
                this.docs = query.results
            }   
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
```

This works at least client side. Will this work for proper SSR? I mean, in `asyncData()` (which is invoked server side), `this` is not accessible, nor the `data()`. If this is the right solution, what's the deal for using `asyncData()` over `fetch()` anymore?

Comment: your questions are answered in the docs https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/ fetch is called on server-side when rendering the route, and on client-side when navigating. *At least, client side* `fetchOnServer: false`? *will this work for proper SSR?* yes.

Comment: Well, i DO want to fetch on server, especially for product detail Page (for SEO). My only doubt Is that I don't know if the code i wrote Is valid even on server side. Furthermore what are the real differences on using ```asyncData```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESOLVED: Nuxt prompted me with a tiny warning saying that "node-fetch" at least at version 2.6.0 is required. For some reason mine was at 2.1.2.

Answer (score 7):

As far as SSR is concerned, `fetch` is used the same way `asyncData` is used (although there is a difference in page transition timing).

The difference between `fetch` and `asyncData`:

- `asyncData` does not have access to `this`, while `fetch` (in Nuxt >= 2.12) does.
- `asyncData`'s return value sets the data of the component, while `fetch`'s return value does not because `fetch` already has access to `this`, so it could set `data` props directly.
- `fetch` is controlled by two [options](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/fetch#options) (`fetchOnServer` and `fetchDelay`), while `asyncData` has no options. When `fetchOnServer` (`true` by default) is set to `false`, the `fetch` hook is only called client-side.
- `fetch` is coupled with the `$fetchState` object, which provides `pending` and `timestamp` (related to the current state of the fetch operation); and the `error` function (allows you to display an error message). Note that `asyncData` is also provided the `error` function in its `context` argument.
- `fetch` allows for faster page transitions (according to [RFC 27](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/27)).
- `asyncData` is only available to pages, while `fetch` can be used by any component (including pages).

Aside from the differences above, the semantics of the two methods are identical.

It seems `fetch` is unofficially the successor of `asyncData` even though both exist simultaneously without a deprecation notice. Since `fetch` provides more functionality and addresses the problems of `asyncData`, I would reccomend using `fetch` exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to have a loading state for your page components you could use the data with asyncData,

```
        data(){
            return{
                loading: true
            }
        },

        async asyncData(context) {
            try{
                const res = await context.app.$prismic.api.query(context.app.$prismic.predicates.at('my.category.uid', context.app.$route.params.sub))
                const el = res.results[0]
                const query = await context.app.$prismic.api.query([context.app.$prismic.predicates.at('document.type','sub-category'), context.app.$prismic.predicates.at('my.sub-category.category', el.id)], { orderings: '[my.sub-category.position, my.sub-category.title]' })
                const docs = query.results
                const loading = false
                return {docs, el, loading}
            }   
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
```

if you use prismic, (and if you didn't register it as a plugin) you could inject prismic into the context through a plugin

```
import prismic from 'prismic-javascript'

export default (inject) => {

    inject('prismic', prismic)
}
```

So now you have access to $prismic in the context.

Another approach that I am using when dealing with loading states is using a store module for handling the state of the request.

`plugins/loading.js`

```
export default ({store},inject) => {
    inject('changeLoading', function(){
            store.dispatch('changeLoading')
        }
    )
}
```

`store/index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
    loading: false
});

export const mutations = {
    CHANGE_LOADING(state){
        state.loading = !state.loading
    }
}

export const actions = {
    changeLoading({commit}){
        commit('CHANGE_LOADING')
    }
}

export const getters = {
    getLoading(state){
        return state.loading
    }
}
```

so now instead of having a local loading state inside your components you would have a centralized state inside your store that you can change and get.

```
        data(){
            return{
                loading: this.$store.getters['getLoading']
            }
        },

        async asyncData(context) {
            try{
                context.app.$changeLoading()
                const prismicData = await context.app.$prismic(...)
                context.app.$changeLoading()
                return {prismicData}
            }   
            catch (e) {
                context.app.$changeLoading()
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for reporting your experience man. But I want to understand how to use the new fetch..

Comment: you can read more about fetch vs asyncdata here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251437/difference-between-asyncdata-vs-fetch , and yes, fetch is called server side aswell, so from a SEO standpoint, you are good, you can also check if SSR works with fetch by inspecting the page source.

Comment: thanks, but they changed the ```fetch``` hook with the 2.12 version"

Comment: changes now allow to use `this` and other stuff like `$fetchState.pending`, `$fetchState.error`, `$fetchState.timestamp`, https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/ . And one more thing is that fetch can be used in all components, while asyncData is only used in pages components.