# Vue/Nuxt: trying to understand SSR

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I've used Vue as a client-side library for years but I unfortunately never dove into server-side rendering, or understand it much, for that matter.  I was watching a few tutorials on it where it gave an example of normal client-side fetching with the `mount()` hook.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in items">
         <div> {{ item.name }} </div>
     </div>
</template>
data() {
   return {
     items: []
   }
}

mount() {
   fetch('http://www.myendpoint.com')
   .then(response => {
     this.items = response;
   }
}
```

vs using Nuxt's asyncData option instead:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in items">
         <div> {{ item.name }} </div>
     </div>
</template>

asyncData() {
   fetch('http://www.myendpoint.com')
   .then(response => {
     this.items = response;
   }
}
```

does this just mean that `async data would run long before` mount`would ever run since it's run before the component is even loaded so the data will be ready?   What happens if that fetch call takes a while to load then...doesn't the same side effect happen?  Rather than a component without data ready using`mount()` if the fetch takes long, you'd just have nothing at all loaded until the fetch completes if using SSR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt is basically a Vue app but with some server logic done before serving the SPA.

Here are the 2 ways of using some data fetching hooks in Nuxt:

- `fetch()` (it's actual hook's name, nothing related to the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)), I do recommend to use this one
- `asyncData` (pretty much the same but less flexible although can block the page render until all the data is properly fetched)

More info can be found between both here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching

---

A whole question is available here too: [Difference between Asyncdata vs Fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49251437/8816585)

Lastly, you probably saw the lifecyle for Vue: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram
Here is the one of Nuxt, which adds a bit more layers to Vue's SPA only ones: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle