# How to make an intersection between 2 datasets in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios, nuxt.js

I tried to get data from api with params which come from an argument in a v-for.
In `findUser` method, I can `console.log` the data I'm looking for. But I can't get it at the end of `findUser`, why?

I know there is an `async` method to get it but I don't understand how to manage it to make it work with what I want to do;
I also thought about calling the two API at the same time, but the result is the same, I don't know how to manage it.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>Listes Reçues</h4>
    <p v-for="element in results" id="flex-list" :key="element.list_id">
      {{ element.list_name }} de {{ findUser(element.user_id) }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      results: '',
      nickname: '',
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$axios
      .get(`/api/listReceived/${this.$auth.user[0].user_id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.results = res.data
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.results))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  },
  methods: {
    findUser(id) {
      console.log(id)
      let data = ''
      this.$axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/userdata/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          data = res.data[0].nickname
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err)
        })
      return data
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of my top answer which was quite not on point regarding the question but still relevant, here is an example on how to handle an intersection properly.

I did not used an endpoint but mocked the data locally in `data()` hence why I keep my post above.

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <h1 class="p-4 bg-green-700 rounded-md">
      List of users ordered by their according message
    </h1>
    <!-- <pre>{{ messages }}</pre> -->
    <section>
      <div v-for="user in groupedMessages" :key="user.id" class="mt-4">
        <p>
          User: <b>{{ user.name }}</b>
        </p>

        <aside>
          Messages:
          <span v-if="!user.messages.length">No messages actually</span>
        </aside>
        <p v-for="message in user.messages" :key="message.id">
          <span class="italic">- {{ message.text }}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// ES version of lodash, lighter overall
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es'

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Hello world',
          userId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Nice cool message',
          userId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: 'Still for the first user?',
          userId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          text: 'Yep, apparently...',
          userId: 1,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          text: "Eh, surprise, I'm a sneaky one...",
          userId: 3,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          text: 'Oh, a second one.',
          userId: 2,
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          text: "You're damn right!!",
          userId: 2,
        },
      ],
      users: [
        {
          name: 'Patrick',
          id: 1,
          messages: [],
        },
        {
          name: 'Pablo',
          id: 2,
          messages: [],
        },
        {
          name: 'Unkown author',
          id: 5,
          messages: [],
        },
        {
          name: 'Escobar',
          id: 3,
          messages: [],
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    groupedMessages() {
      // we use that to avoid any kind of further mutation to the initial `users` array
      const clonedUsers = cloneDeep(this.users)
      // we do loop on each message and find a corresponding user for it
      this.messages.forEach((message) =>
        clonedUsers.forEach((user) => {
          if (user.id === message.userId) {
            user.messages.push(message)
          }
        })
      )
      return clonedUsers
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The [github repo is available](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt-harry-potter-api), please do not pay attention to the unrelated name of it.

This is how it looks [on Netlify](https://so-grouped-users.netlify.app/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`created()` is totally fine with Vue but usually you do use `fetch()` and `asyncData()` hooks in Nuxt.
Here is the basic idea using [JSONplaceholder's API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

Here is a possible `/pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <h1 class="p-4 bg-green-700 rounded-md">
      List of users from JSONplaceholder
    </h1>
    <section class="mt-4">
      <p v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
        {{ user.name }}  {{ user.email }} ~
        <nuxt-link
          :to="{ name: 'users-id', params: { id: user.id } }"
          class="border-b-4 border-green-500"
        >
          Check details
        </nuxt-link>
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.users = await this.$axios.$get('/users')
  },
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  @apply bg-gray-800 text-gray-100;
}
</style>
```

And the detailed page aka `/pages/users/_id.vue` using the [`fetch()` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook).

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <nuxt-link class="p-4 bg-purple-700 rounded-md" :to="{ name: 'index' }">
      Go back
    </nuxt-link>

    <h2>User details ID: # {{ $route.params.id }}</h2>
    <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Loading user's info...</p>
    <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">Error while fetching user</p>
    <div v-else>
      <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.phone }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.website }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.company.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UserId',
  data() {
    return {
      user: {},
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.user = await this.$axios.$get(`/users/${this.$route.params.id}`)
  },
}
</script>
```

I do prefer this approach because it's not blocking the render, you can add some [smooth skeleton](https://buefy.org/documentation/skeleton) to still let the user know that something is happening. On top of that, `fetch()` is available on both components and pages while `asyncData()` is only for pages.
It also gives the nice [`$fetchState` helper](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#accessing-the-fetch-state) that can also be quite handy!

---

Here is the same `/pages/users/_id.vue` page using the [`asyncData() hook`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#async-data).

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
    <nuxt-link class="p-4 bg-purple-700 rounded-md" :to="{ name: 'index' }">
      Go back
    </nuxt-link>

    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.phone }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.website }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.company.name }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UserId',
  async asyncData({ route, $axios }) {
    const user = await $axios.$get(`/users/${route.params.id}`)
    return { user }
  },
}
</script>
```

Main benefit of using `asyncData` is the fact that it's more safe and that it's blocking the render (can be either a pro or a con, more of a con for me personally).

Here are some [other in-depth answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251437/difference-between-asyncdata-vs-fetch) comparing `fetch()` vs `asyncData()`.
Check out this [handy blog article](https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12) on the subject and also this [dev.to clone example](https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/build-dev-to-clone-with-nuxt-new-fetch/).

---

Finally, if you want to take the SSG path and optimize the whole thing with the least amount of API calls once on the client-side, you can also check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68431975/8816585).