# Nuxt: can't set data property on server in 'created' lifecycle

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I try to set a value on a property in the "created" lifecycle method - on the server - but the value remains null (its default value).

(I use typescript and class based components)

```js
export default class FunClass extends Vue {
  @Prop() data!: any;
  myProp : any = null;

   created() {
    if (process.server) {
      this.myProp = this.data.interestingData;
    }
  }
}
```

So there must be some rule that I missed?
I tried `asyncData` but it only works on pages (and I can't access any props from there).

Comment: You can either use the `fetch()` hook or `asyncData()` one. Both are a bit different but give you access to quite some things actually. Did you gave a read [to this](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#data-fetching)? If you want to access it from anywhere, use the `fetch()` hook.

Comment: @kissu Fantastic, that solved the problem. You could add it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle your data on any place (page, component, layout etc...), you can use the `fetch()` hook, it's quite handy thanks to it's helpers like `$fetchState.pending` and it's not blocking, hence you could display some nice [skeletons](https://buefy.org/documentation/skeleton) while the data is loading, like Instagram/Facebook.

For more info, you can check this documentation regarding [data fetching](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#data-fetching) in Nuxt.

If you want to have more differences regarding `fetch() vs asyncData`, here is a [handy question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49251437/8816585) wit plenty of various great answers.